# Accessing Type Parameters Using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How do I find type parameter values passed to a super class using reflection?

For example, given `Bar.class`, how do I find that it passes `Integer.class` to `Foo`'s type parameter `T`?

```
public class Foo<T> {
}

public class Bar extends Foo<Integer> {
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) Bar.class.getGenericSuperclass();
System.out.println(type.getRawType()); // prints; class Foo
Type[] actualTypeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();
System.out.println(actualTypeArguments[0]); // prints; class java.lang.Integer
```

This only works because Bar is a class which extends a specific Foo.  If you declared a variable like the following, you wouldn't be able to determine the parameter type of intFoo at runtime.

```
Foo<Integer> intFoo = new Foo<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Bar extends Foo<Integer> {

 public Class getTypeClass {
   ParameterizedType parameterizedType =
     (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperClass();
  return (Class) parameterizedtype.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
 }

}
```

The given above should work in most of the practical situations,**but not guaranteed**,  because of type erasure, there is no way to do this directly.

Comment: Although in this case you could have getTypeClass() return Class<Integer> or Integer.class. ;)

Comment: @Peter Yes. I just tried to show the process in generic way :)